# How to check values in mysql for preceeding rows and using them to find sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find the time, that the system that is based on this table has elapsed while having code '100', so firstly i thought that I have to find the newest row of the xID group and after that, check the previous rows if their code is 100, if so i have to proceed with previous previous row till it gets a 200 value, after that it finds the time from the following row of 200 hundred till now (value 100).

```
ID     xID      createdDate          CODE
 1     '1', '2019-07-27 11:52:01',  '100'
 2     '1', '2019-07-27 11:54:01',  '200'
 3     '2', '2019-09-03 05:10:02',  '200'
 4     '2', '2019-09-03 05:12:02',  '200'
 5     '3', '2019-09-02 05:12:02',  '200'
 6     '3', '2019-09-02 05:12:02',  '100'
 7     '3', '2019-09-02 05:12:02',  '200'
 8     '4', '2019-09-02 05:13:02',  '200'
 9     '5', '2019-09-03 05:10:03',  '200'
 10    '6', '2018-12-13 05:03:02',  '200'
```

So this query must for each group of xID find the total time for which the system has been with code 100 until now. Hope I've been clear. And here is the sql so far.

```
select id, createdDate, code
from wlogs 
where id in (
select max(id)
from wlogs
group by xid
)
order by xid;
```

EDIT:
MYSQL VERSION 8.0
RESULT must be something like this where the column totTimeWithCode100 must show the time in seconds or minutes doesn't matter, for each type of xID.

```
xID   totTimeWithCode100
'1',   '500'   
'2',   '2'  
'3',   '33'
'4',   '200'
'5',   '40'
'6',   '200'
```

[These rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C08lO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to MySQL 8.0, we can use of user-defined variables (in a way that is unsupported) in carefully crafted SQL that takes advantage of behavior that is repeatably observed but not guaranteed. (The MySQL Reference Manual warns specifically about this usage of user-defined variables.)

Something like this:

```
SELECT s.xid                            AS `xID`
     , IFNULL(SUM(s.secs_in_code100),0) AS `totTimeWithCode100`
  FROM (
         SELECT IF(@prev_xid = t.xid AND @prev_code = 100, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,@prev_date,t.createddate),0) AS secs_in_code100
              , @prev_xid  := t.xid          AS xid
              , @prev_date := t.createddate  AS createddate 
              , @prev_code := t.code         AS code
           FROM ( SELECT @prev_xid  := ''
                       , @prev_date := '1970-01-02 03:00'
                       , @prev_code := ''
                ) i
          CROSS
           JOIN wlogs t
          ORDER
             BY t.xid
              , t.createddate
       ) s
 GROUP BY s.xid
 ORDER BY s.xid
```

---

With MySQL 8.0, we can avoid the user-defined variables by using analytic/window functions.

Comment: I'm analyzin it but how could it be done in MySQL 8.0 with windowing. I think I might  upgrade to it.

Comment: With MySQL 8.0, we could make use of `LAG()` window function to access values from previous row, instead of preserving the values from previous rows in user defined variables.

Comment: @spencer7593 the OP uses mariadb 10.1, so no window functions.

Comment: @Shadow Yes but I can upgrade to 8.0 if necessary and if it works better with windowing, I dont know how it works either way.

Comment: MariaDB-10.2 has window functions.

Comment: @spencer7593 Is your code that you wrote changable to using it with LAG() function, because i have now version 8.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want by finding all the rows with `CODE = 100` for a given `xID` that are immediately followed (in time) by a row with `CODE != 100`. This can be done by `LEFT JOIN`ing the rows with `CODE != 100` to the preceding row *if* that row has `CODE = 100`:

```
SELECT w.xID, COALESCE(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, w1.createdDate, w2.createdDate)), 0) AS totTimeWithCode100
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT xID FROM wlogs) w
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
           FROM wlogs
           WHERE CODE = 100) w1 ON w1.xID = w.xID
LEFT JOIN wlogs w2 ON w2.xID = w1.xID
                  AND w2.createdDate = (SELECT MIN(createdDate)
                                        FROM wlogs w3
                                        WHERE w3.xID = w1.xID AND
                                              w3.createdDate > w1.createdDate)
GROUP BY w.xID
ORDER BY w.xID;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8eaVyRPPsybdgWpswrfm8p/1)

Comment: Would this correctly handle a case when a 100 code is followed by another 100 code? OP sample data doesn't include an example of this, but there's nothing in the spec that say that it wouldn't happen. How should "total time in 100 code" be calculated when there are a series of 100 code rows with no intervening non-1000 code?

Comment: @spencer7593 indeed it would not have. As you say it wasn't in the example but could possibly occur. I have edited with a new query that will sum all those times and a new demo.